# What's the right way to set an NSError outparam from inside an autoreleasepool block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease

I have a method like this:

```
- (void)processAThing:(id)thing error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error
{
    @autoreleasepool {

          // Start processing.

          // Find some partway through error..
          if (error) {
              *error = [NSError errorWithDomain...];
              return NO;
          }

          // More processing.
    }
}
```

This is broken and crashes, because the NSError is autoreleased, and when the return happens, the pool is drained, so the thing that the caller gets is now bogus.

I know I could significantly redesign the method so I collect all error cases outside the autorelease block, but I want to understand whether there's a correct way of handling the error object in this situation. I can't alloc/init a speculative NSError outside the pool block, because the domain and code properties are readonly (and I still think the reference would disappear when the method returns).

It solves the problem if I change the method declaration to this:

```
- (void)processAThing:(id)thing error:(NSError * __strong *)error
```

But then I need to fuss around at the call site in a nonstandard way, and this seems egregious to make the caller pay the price for my internal autoreleasepool.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Changing the signature to `(NSError * __strong *)error` actually seems like a reasonable alternative to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this problem myself. In this case, I think you just need to declare a new strong reference just before the `@autoreleasepool`, and set the method argument just after the `@autoreleasepool` block from that temporary reference.

```
- (void)processAThing:(id)thing error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error {
  __strong NSError *errOut = nil;
  @autoreleasepool {
    // do your stuff and set errOut instead of error
  }
  if (error) {
    *error = errOut;
  }
}
```

(typed in browser, not error checked by compiler)

As for your premature return, I guess you'll have to use a jump label (even if it's not pretty).

Comment: you don't need to write `__strong`. It is that by default

Comment: Yes, I put it there just to clarify.

Comment: Thanks Erik. Sounds like there's no other obvious pattern to use except minimizing the scope of the autorelease block and setting the outparam outside of it.

Comment: BTW, if you need multiple returns (for example because of multiple error reasons), you can wrap your whole autoreleasepool in a `@try` block, and then do the *error = errOut dance in the `@finally` block (`@catch` is optional). This will ensure the out-error gets assigned properly before return in any case (thanks to my colleague Stephan for coming up with this).