# Call Method that assigns NSError in Block Crashes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

I'd like to understand why this crashes with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. It returns from the method call fine, but then crashes immediately afterwards on the `[self runMethodThatAssignsError:&error]` .

I've [found a similar post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907726/setting-nserror-within-a-block-using-arc), but it doesn't explain what is going on, and is rather old.

```
- (void)checkError {
    NSError *error;
    [self runMethodThatAssignsError:&error]; // crashes after returning
    NSLog(@"success");
}

- (BOOL)runMethodThatAssignsError:(NSError **)error {
    [@[@1] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"1" code:7 userInfo:@{}];
    }];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: `__block NSError *blockError = nil; [@[@1] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) { blockError = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"1" code:7 userInfo:@{}];}]; if (blockError) *error = blockError; return N0;`?

Comment: @Larme Yeah, that's the question, is that always required? There's no way around that? If so, why?

Comment: FYI - Never do `*error = ...` without first making sure that `error` isn't `nil`. Never dereference a nil pointer.

Comment: If you write `NSUInteger value = 0;` before the `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` and then a try to set its value inside the block, the compiler should warn you (compile error or warning) asking for a `__block`. So I'd say it's the same here.

Comment: @Larme So the compiler is just failing to warn me about something that will cause a crash, and that's really what's going on?

Comment: That's my guess. But I'm not an expert on that part.

Comment: @Larme Don't you mean `if (error) *error = blockError;`

Comment: Good eyes. Seems indeed more senseful.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489969/whats-the-right-way-to-set-an-nserror-outparam-from-inside-an-autoreleasepool-b

Comment: @rmaddy Technically, a check against an `NSError **` pointer should be for `NULL`, not `nil`. `nil` is supposed to be used for object pointers (i.e. `NSError *`), not pointers *to* object pointers, although in practice they both have the same value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Running your example code in Instruments, it appears that `-[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]` is wrapping its block in an autorelease pool. Since `NSError **` pointers are, by default, implicitly assumed to be `__autoreleasing`, your `NSError` object is autoreleased when it is assigned to `*error`, and consequently reaped by `-[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]`'s autorelease pool.

There are two ways to fix this. The first one is to use a local variable outside of the block, to cause ARC to retain it until after the enumeration has finished:

```
- (BOOL)runMethodThatAssignsError:(NSError **)error {
    __block NSError *_error = nil;

    [@[@1] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        _error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"1" code:7 userInfo:@{}];
    }];

    if (error) *error = _error;

    return NO;
}
```

Alternatively, you can just declare the `error` parameter as `__strong`, which will prevent the `NSError` from being put in the autorelease pool in the first place. Note that this should only be done if the clients of this method are always going to be using ARC, because otherwise it will probably cause the errors to leak as the clients will not expect to have to release them, due to this approach being unconventional.

```
- (BOOL)runMethodThatAssignsError:(NSError * __strong *)error {
    [@[@1] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if (error) *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"1" code:7 userInfo:@{}];
    }];

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I recommend the first approach. Using `NSError * __strong *` is very unconventional.

Comment: Apparently, this is documented, `Values allocated within the block will be deallocated after the block is executed. Use retain to explicitly maintain those values.` - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1415846-enumerateobjectsusingblock